# Qt SQL - ERROR (42601): syntax error at or near

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, c++, postgresql, qt

Atualmente estou desenvolvendo um programa para auxiliar no gerenciamento de um quartel em minha cidade, estou utilizando `Qt` para criar a interface gráfica e outras bibliotecas necessárias como as de manipulação de bancos de dados, para o servidor estou utilizando o `postgres`, ao tentar criar uma tabela eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Falha ao criar a tabela va_atiradores:  QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"(\"\nLINE 4: cpf integer(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n                   ^\n(42601)")
```

Além disso ao encerrar o programa a runtime do visual studio me acusa um erro de corrupção da heap:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o trecho do código responsável por criar a tabela:

```
bool Atirador::insert(QStringList &data)
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();

    const QString sqlTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sch_tg.va_atiradores(\n"
                       "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                       "nome varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                       "cpf integer(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                       "rg integer(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                       "ra integer(30) UNIQUE,\n"
                       "nPai varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                       "nMae varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                       "dataNasc date NOT NULL,\n"
                       "estdCvl integer NOT NULL,\n"
                       "cidade varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "cep integer(10) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "estado varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "uf varchar(2) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "rua varchar(500) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "nCasa integer,\n"
                       "bairro varchar(500) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "cel integer(30) UNIQUE,\n"
                       "tel integer(30) UNIQUE,\n"
                       "tipoAtr integer NOT NULL,\n"
                       "status integer NOT NULL,\n"
                       "cadPor varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                       "ultServ date,\n"
                       "pontos integer,\n"
                       "servicos integer)\0";

    QSqlQuery createTableQuery(db);

    if(!createTableQuery.exec(sqlTable)){

        qCritical() << "Falha ao criar a tabela va_atiradores: " << createTableQuery.lastError();

        createTableQuery.finish();

        return true;
    }

    createTableQuery.finish();

    db.close();

    return true;
}
```

Em primeiro momento pensei ser algum erro de algum caractere não escapado, mas ao testar o código sql na ferramenta de query do `pgAdmin 4` eu recebo o mesmo erro:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:                        cpf integer(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 189
```

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar um `StringBuilder` para construir a _query_ e utilizar o `AppendLine()` para dar _line feeds_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mensagem de erro apresenta erro de sintaxe na montagem da *query* na linha `cpf integer(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE`; você está querendo um inteiro mas está definindo um tamanho para ele, o que não é necessário.

```
const QString sqlTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sch_tg.va_atiradores(\n"
                   "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                   "nome varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                   "cpf integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                   "rg integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                   "ra integer UNIQUE,\n"
                   "nPai varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                   "nMae varchar(1000) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                   "dataNasc date NOT NULL,\n"
                   "estdCvl integer NOT NULL,\n"
                   "cidade varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "cep integer NOT NULL,\n"
                   "estado varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "uf varchar(2) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "rua varchar(500) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "nCasa integer,\n"
                   "bairro varchar(500) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "cel integer UNIQUE,\n"
                   "tel integer UNIQUE,\n"
                   "tipoAtr integer NOT NULL,\n"
                   "status integer NOT NULL,\n"
                   "cadPor varchar(250) NOT NULL,\n"
                   "ultServ date,\n"
                   "pontos integer,\n"
                   "servicos integer)\0";
```

Removi essas definições, agora não deve ter mais problemas